# Microsoft KMS Office 2016 - replace Client PC?

Tags: microsoft-office, license

We have about 40 Computers in our network and we recently start to manage our MS Office activations over KMS.

Since we have to replace a Computer in our network every now and then (about 4 per year), we also need to "move" the Office installations to new hardware.

If I type

> ospp.vbs /unpkey:value

on the client, the Office license should be removed and freed for the new hardware, right?

However, typing

> slmgr.vbs /dlv [ActivationID]

still shows the same "Current count" as before.

How do I inform the KMS host that I want to replace a specific client and reuse the old client's activation on a new hardware?

Comment: You might be running into a situation where you are not reaching the minimum number of clients required to activate additional installs.  How many clients are you doing this too?

Comment: I know about the minimum clients of 5 situation. Right now, I have about 12 clients activated.

Comment: Please provide the output of `ospp.vbs /dstatusall`.  Sanitize and condense whatever information you feel is required.  The purpose of the command is to determine if your previous command to unregister a client actually worked.  You might also run `ospp.vbs /rearm`, however, I must warn you that if I am not mistaken, there is a limit to the number of times you can rearm your Office installations (in a given timeframe).  I don't know that timeframe, I have not had to use this particular tool, in my previous office deployments (I have only ever used Slmgr.vbs).

Comment: @Ramhound - I already uninstalled MS Office, so right now I don't have ospp.vbs on that PC anymore. There's going to be a new Laptop to be installed within the next two weeks, so if there's no other possibility, I get back to it when I replace that one.

Comment: This question cannot be answered without that information.  However, the command I requested, can actually be run on any client with that script